# Linked list deep copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I am implementing a linked list class' copy constructor which will make a deep copy. This is the code that i have:

```
List( const List & rhs ) {
        Node* rhsFront = rhs.header->next;
        Node* prev = header;
        while (rhsFront) {
            prev->next = new Node(rhsFront->data, nullptr);
            rhsFront = rhsFront->next;
            prev = prev->next;
        }
}
```

However, it crashes at this line:

```
prev->next = new Node(rhsFront->data, nullptr);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You went wrong by failing to initialize the class member in your copy constructor, resulting in an uninitialized pointer dereference, and undefined behavior. In general, if your class has a working `insert()` or `append()` function, a deep copy constructor can be implemented by delegating it to the default copy constructor, iterating over the values in the list being copied from, and then using the existing class methods to initialize the copied-to list. This is a completely wrong way to implement a copy constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node* prev = header;
```

I would guess the header there not to be initialised, thus causing the prev->next to be a random pointer (most likely something like 0) and trying to write to that point crashes the program. If so, this might work.

```
List( const List & rhs ) {
    Node* rhsFront = rhs.header->next;
    header = new Node(rhs.header->data, nullptr);
    Node* prev = header;
    while (rhsFront) {
        prev->next = new Node(rhsFront->data, nullptr);
        rhsFront = rhsFront->next;
        prev = prev->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you starting at next and not header. 
Node* prev = header; where is header defined? Have you already allocated the memory needed? instead start from header and copy over.

```
List( const List & rhs ) {
    Node* rhsFront = rhs.header;
    Node* prev = header;
    while (rhsFront) {
        prev = new Node(rhsFront->data, rhsFront->next);
        rhsFront = rhsFront->next;
        prev = prev->next;
    }
}
```

This way you are copying all nodes and not skipping the header. Hope this makes sense. 
Also the actual exception you are getting might give a clue as to which access is NPE.