# Guidance for implementing a Copy Constructor into a Doubly Linked List Class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have been attempting to implement a copy constructor, that creates a deep copy, for a doubly linked list class. I have been running into the issue where 
the head and tail the push_back() function attempts to operate on are undefined or a nullptr. If anyone has any experience with doubly linked list, please feel free to give any help.

My Copy Constructor function:

```
//copy constructor
DoubleLinkedList::DoubleLinkedList(const DoubleLinkedList& dll)
{
    copyList(dll);
}
```

My copyList function definition:

```
void DoubleLinkedList::copyList(const DoubleLinkedList& listToBeCopied)
{
    if (listToBeCopied.head == head) //checks to make sure that the list that is being copied isn't the same as the one it is copying to
    {
        return;
    }
    listToBeCopied.resetIterator(); //sets the iterator to head
    while (listToBeCopied.hasMore()) //continues to run as long as iterator is not equal to a nullptr (tail->next).
    {
        push_back((listToBeCopied.next())); //takes the data from the iterator and pushes it to the back of the list.
    }
}
```

My push_back() function defintion:

```
// insert str at back of list
void DoubleLinkedList::push_back(const AMString& str)
{
    Node *temp = new Node(str);
    if (head == nullptr)
{
    head = tail = temp;
    head->prev = nullptr;
    //cout << "\"" << str << "\" was added to the front and back (push_back).\n\n";
}
else
{
    temp->prev = tail;
    tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;
    //cout << "\"" << str << "\" was added the back.\n\n";
}
count++;
```

}

Comment: Well, initialize `head` and `tail` to suitable values (likely `nullptr`) before calling `copyList`.

Comment: They are initialized either to a node or nullptr.

Comment: This lacks a [mcve], as relevant code for the `resetIterator`, `hasMore`, and `next` functions is missing, as is the declaration of the `Node` class (in particular, the constructor called by `push_back`).

Comment: There was similar question before: [linked list deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320856/linked-list-deep-copy-constructor).

Comment: Not in the code you've shown, they aren't.